# VBA Loop through sheet and check accuracy

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to get a loop to work.

What i need to happen is to loop over a sheet and if address matches in column A does column W have a value, if all instances of address have values in column W then `GoTo end_nothing`. If only some matches have data in column W then continue with sub.

The problem I am having with my code is that the first entry it matches, it exits the sub without looping over the rest.

My Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim add_WIR_check, lastRow_WIR As Long
Dim address_Check  As String: address_Check = sheets("Auto Checklist").cells(3, 2).value

lastRow_WIR = sheets("Works Instruction Record").cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

***** Unprotect Sheet

For add_WIR_check = 3 To lastRow_WIR
If sheets("Works Instruction Record").cells(add_WIR_check, 1) = address_Check Then
    If sheets("Works Instruction Record").cells(add_WIR_check, 23) <> "" Then
        GoTo end_nothing
    End If
End If
Next add_WIR_check

***** Additional code here

end_nothing:
***** Protect sheet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VBA code snippet does not comply with the business logic as described: you must loop through all matching rows in the range to find out if all cells in the Column "W" contain value. It may be achieved by using auxiliary `Boolean` var `ok`, like shown below:

```
Dim ok as boolean
ok = True
For add_WIR_check = 3 To lastRow_WIR
If sheets("Works Instruction Record").cells(add_WIR_check, 1) = address_Check Then
    If Not (sheets("Works Instruction Record").cells(add_WIR_check, 23) <> "") Then
        ok = False
End If
End If
Next add_WIR_check
```

Upon completion, the var `ok` value will indicate if all cells in Column "W" of the matching rows contain values.

Hope this may help.

Comment: That you Alex, this worked perfectly, and it runs so fast! Really Appreciate the help!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. Best regards,